# U.E.F.I. Secure Boot Problems

Tags: secure-boot

Unified Extensible Firmware Interface Secure-Boot on Ubuntu 16.04  is blocking system updates and downloads. Can one disengage it or is there a way to not disengage it and have it perform its function without blocking downloads.

Comment: Disable Secure Boot. No "disengagement"required. Thank you for spelling it out but we're quite familiar with the acronym ;-)

Comment: Secure Boot shouldn't stop system updates or downloads. In the Ubuntu context, we usually disable Secure Boot if we're trying to load unsigned kernel drivers. You can turn if off in your BIOS. You may have something else going on. Can you please describe where/how you see a problem?

Comment: Well my computer informs me that the  U.E.F. I.  needs to be toggled to allow the latest Ubuntu update to update. The only aspect of my system that does update is the Firefox browser - otherwise nothing.